# How to handle ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint when data contains lot of duplicates

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

My application contains lot of duplicate data, so basically its my data issue, but I would want to proceed further and insert data which are not duplicate.

I am using spring boot with jpa and postgres Sql.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="city_Info")
public class City {
    @Id
    @Column

    private Integer city_id;
    @Column
    private String city;
    @Column
    private String country;
}
```

Here Primary key consists of city and country.

Application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PostgreSQL 9.5+, you can "upsert" your duplicate rows by using `ON CONFLICT` clause:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: Thanks Linas. i used this approach and used custom save method in repository to use ON CONFLICT.